# Could not find Spring 4 from Maven in Spring Tool Suite 3.7.3.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring.

First, I installed Java 1.8.0_92 on my MAC

Secondly, I downloaded STS 3.7.3.RELEASE and have it running.

Finally, I followed the instruction to upgrade a Maven project -> Dynamic Web Project -> Spring MVC project.

However, in the last step, when adding dependencies and looking for org.springframework.spring-webmvc, only 3.1.1.RELEASE was displayed, I didn't see anything relating to Spring 4 as the guide had shown me.

I have no idea what's going on with my installation. Any one know?
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I solved it.

**Windows -> Show View -> Others -> Maven Repositories**

In the Maven Repositories view, **expand Global Repositories -> right click on central -> Update Index**

It took a while to update the index. After that, I got everything